# How to manually escape a boolean value for a mySQL Database insert in CakePHP?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

i'm having the following code:

```
  /** @var DboSource $db */
  $db = $this->getDataSource();

  var_dump($db->value($open, 'boolean'));
  die;

  $this->query(
    'INSERT INTO foo(`client_id`, `open`, `modified`, `created`) VALUES(:clientId, :open, NOW(), NOW()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE modified = now();',
    [
      ':clientId' => $db->value($clientId, 'integer'),
      ':open' => $db->value($open, 'boolean')
    ]
  );
```

`$open` is a boolean value, the `'open'`-column is defined as `tinyint(1)`. When wrapping $open with `$db->value($open, 'boolean')` the result is `'1'`, `'0'` (see the single quotes).

Unfortunately this output leads to a new record with `open = false` (as `'1'` is not properly inserted as `true`)

If I use `$db->boolean($open)` as option, everything's working correctly.

But I think, `$db->value()` should do the same job as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at when and how `DboSource::value()` is being used internally, this is the expected behavior. If it wouldn't do what it does, then values wouldn't get prepared properly for `Model::save()` operations.

`DboSource::value()` internally passes the "booleanized" value (`DboSource::boolean($value, true)` this already adds quotes) to `PDO::quote()`, where the value is going to be quoted anyways no matter what, ie `0`, `1`, `'0'`, `'1'`, `true`, or `false`, it will always return a quoted value, that is `'0'`, `'1'` or even `''` (for `false`, which is equal to `0`).

The problem with your code is, that values passed to the second argument of `Model::query()` are finally being passed to [**`PDOStatement::execute()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) (**[.../DboSource.php#L458](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5.8/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php#L458)**), which treats all values as strings and escapes them accordingly, so finally in your query a `'1'` will end up as `'\'1\''`, hence the problems.

TL;DR

This seems to be the expected behavior, it's just poorly documented. So when using the second argument of `Model::query()`, sanitize the values if necessary (ie cast to integers, booleans, strings, etc), but do not escape them, escape them only when you manually insert them in the actual query string (**which should however be avoided whenever possible**)!